# Powershell returning objects from GCI and XPATH

Tags: powershell, xpath

I have this simple script to return all my xmls in a given directory, listing the name and lastwritetime.

```
$xmlfiles = gci c:\temp\importexport\JDW*EmployeeImport*.xml |
Select-Object Name, LastWriteTime
```

I also want to further filter the list to those that contain a particular attribute called *Password*:

```
$Password = $xmlfiles | Select-Xml -XPATH "//User" | 
Select -expandproperty node | where {$_.password} |
Select id, firstName, lastName, statusCode
```

The problem I have is that I want to combine the *Name* and *LastWriteTime* from the first GCI query, with the other four objects from the XPATH query. When I try to include all six objects I don't get any result:

```
$xmlfiles = gci c:\temp\importexport\JDW*EmployeeImport*.xml |
Select-Object Name, LastWriteTime  
$Password = $xmlfiles | Select-Xml -XPATH "//User" | 
Select -expandproperty node | where {$_.password} |
Select id, firstName, lastName, statusCode
```

If I remove the *Select-Object Name, LastWriteTime* I then get the results, but without the Name and LastWriteTime. If I add this query into the last line along with the other four objects, again, it doesn't return anything

```
$xmlfiles = gci c:\temp\importexport\JDW*EmployeeImport*.xml |
$Password = $xmlfiles | Select-Xml -XPATH "//User" | 
Select -expandproperty node | where {$_.password} |
Select Name, LastWriteTime, id, firstName, lastName, statusCode
```

I've also tried $xmlfiles.Name and $xmlfiles.LastWriteTime too.

Here is the xml

```
<EnterpriseDocument InterfaceName="Employee Interface">
 <BusinessUnitList>
  <BusinessUnit id="1234">
   <User id="1234567" password="anypassword" firstName="John" lastName="Doe">
     <RoleList><Role id="Associate"></Role></RoleList>
     <OrgList><Organization id="0289"/></OrgList>
   </User>
 </BusinessUnit>
</BusinessUnitList>
</Ente‌​rpriseDocument>
```

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Can you show us the XML (or an anonymized sample)?

Comment: Please [edit the question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/38502447/edit) rather than pasting code and data into comments :)